# Payment gateway in visa/master

Tags: c#, asp.net, oscommerce

I am a newbie to asp.net . How to integrate a payment method in visa/master to my website . I have no idea about that . Anyone suggest me a good link .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `barclays ePDQ CPI` or `Paypal`, both support visa/master transactions.

For Barclays Integration have a detailed documentation at: [Barclay Integration Guide](http://www.barclaycard.co.uk/business/existing-customers/activate-epdq-cpi/)

For Paypal Integeration documentaion: [Paypal Integration Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that deals with direct integration with my bank account

Comment: yes you can start it with test accounts and then move it on your live account.

Comment: what will be live url of barclays? i want to move to test account to live account. any help..thanks